# bash-script to remove pdf meta data

Tags: bash, pdf, metadata

I'm pretty new to bash-scripting and I want to remove all metadata from pdf-files from a certain directory and its subfolders.
So i took [this script](http://blog.snapdragon.cc/2015/08/28/shell-function-to-remove-all-metadata-from-pdf/) and tried to put it in a loop.

```
    for file in $(find . -iname '*.pdf')
    do
       pdftk $file dump_data | \
       sed -e 's/\(InfoValue:\)\s.*/\1\ /g' | \
       pdftk $1 update_info - output $file.tmp

       exiftool -all:all= $file.tmp
       exiftool -all:all $file.tmp
       exiftool -extractEmbedded -all:all $file.tmp
       qpdf --linearize $file.tmp $file

       pdftk $file dump_data
       exiftool $file
       pdfinfo -meta $file
done
```

I get an error but I don't unterstand why.

```
Error: No input files.  Exiting.
Errors encountered.  No output created.
```

Anyway, is it a good idea to remove unnecessary information with this method or are there better methods?

Greets

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Agreed. Some sort of `set -x` to find out which lines are complaining. Then you can probably resolve the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks thats a good tipp. Must have been blind yesterday ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version works as intended although it's not beautiful

```
find -name "* *" -type d | rename 's/ /_/g' 
find -name "* *" -type f | rename 's/ /_/g'
# Removes whitespace from directories and files

for file in $(find . -iname '*.pdf')
do

    pdftk $file dump_data | \
    sed -e 's/\(InfoValue:\)\s.*/\1\ /g' | \
    pdftk $file update_info - output $file-clean

    exiftool -all:all= $file-clean
    exiftool -all:all $file-clean
    exiftool -extractEmbedded -all:all $file-clean
    qpdf --linearize $file-clean $file-clean2

    pdftk $file-clean2 dump_data
    exiftool $file-clean2
    pdfinfo -meta $file-clean2
    rm -f $file $file-clean $file-clean_original $file_original
    mv $file-clean2 $file

done

echo finished
```